# Connecting to a specific UIImageView instead of initial View

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am a beginner so please bear with me. I am trying to load a gif onto one of my pages, and so far I have figured out how to do it on the initial screen, but I would like the gif to load on another page instead. I know I should move it out of the 'override func viewDidLoad() {}' function, but I don't know what to do afterwards. Could somebody please help me? Thank you!

Here is the code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("fire", withExtension: "gif")!)
        let imageGif = UIImage.gifWithData(imageData!)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: imageGif)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y:0.0, width:414.0, height: 673.0)
        view.addSubview(imageView)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Assume that the viewDidLoad is an entry point for every view controller. You can override the method always.

Comment: @Armin How do I override the method? Thank you!